# Jquery checkbox assigning value

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox called ChartInfo. I need to update it with checked or unchecked.

```
   $('#ChartInfo').val(<need to update this>);
```

My question is how do I go about assigning a value in .val() on to indicate if it was check or not.

Comment: After reading your question three times I'm unclear about what it is exactly that you're trying to do with regard to the part, _"assigning a value in .val() on to indicate if it was check or not"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use either:

```
$('#ChartInfo').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$('#ChartInfo').prop('checked', false);
```

Examples:

```js
$('#c1').prop('checked', false);
$('#c2').prop('checked', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="c1" type="checkbox" checked>

<input id="c2" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check a checkbox:

```
$('#ChartInfo').attr('checked', true);
```

or unckeck it:

```
$('#ChartInfo').removeAttr('checked');
```

while changing the `value` will change the value sent to sever on submit:

```
$('#ChartInfo').val('foo'); // Will set the value to 'foo' so you can get it server-side
```